# Nested XML parsing in Hive

Tags: xml, hive

I have XML input files like below:

```xml
<company>
    <cname>cat</cname>
    <emp>
        <ename>x</ename>
        <egender>m</egender>
    </emp>
    <emp>
        <ename>y</ename>
        <egender>f</egender>
    </emp>
</company>
```

I want to parse this XML and load into the Hive table.

The required output in Hive table is:

```None
     cname|ename|egender
     cat  |x    | m
     cat  |y    | f
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: "This is very urgent" well... we are not really in a rush. Please post your code, what you've tried so far. We are here to help to you fix your code but not to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You  could certainly use [JAXP to parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/) your xml document.
Alternately, you could use [STaX to parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html) your document. The referenced articles are from the Java Tutorial, and will provide adquate examples to help you figure out how to do this.

Comment: But the files size is more than 100 MB. Is it possible to parse the entire files at a time..?

Comment: The 2 parsers I identified are "streaming" parsers. They will not load the whole file at once, but will load smaller chunks of the file (i.e. streaming), process that chunk, and then read in the next chunk. So the size of the file being processed is unlikely to be a problem. Do not use the SAX parser for this processing, since it needs to load the whole file into memory before processing.